# Why can't I use 'Type' as the name of an enum embedded in a struct?

Tags: swift

The following fails to compile:

```
struct S1 {
    enum Type {
        case One, Two, Three
    }

    let e1 : Type
    let i : Int
}

func f1(e : S1.Type) {
    S1(e1: e, i: 1)
}
```

with error:

```
error: cannot invoke initializer for type 'S1' with an argument list of type '(e1: S1.Type, i: Int)'
    S1(e1: e, i: 1)
    ^
note: expected an argument list of type '(e1: S1.Type, i: Int)'
    S1(e1: e, i: 1)
```

However, if I replace `Type` for the name of the enum with something else, say `Types`, it compiles fine.

Why can't I use `Type` as the name of an enum embedded in a struct?

Comment: type is a keyword used in swift when defining structures

Comment: I'm using Type, not type.

Comment: The error message could definitely be improved.

Comment: out of curiosity, what was the error message?

Comment: It's in the question above, but basically can't invoke with argument list '(e1: S1.Type, i: Int)' because it expected '(e1: S1.Type, i: Int)'. That is, you can't invoke with X because I expected X. Weird.

Comment: I swear I don't know how I missed that you already posted the error.  sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steve was right, it's a keyword. Here's the relevant part of the spec:

> Keywords reserved in particular contexts: associativity, convenience,
>   dynamic, didSet, final, get, infix, inout, lazy, left, mutating, none,
>   nonmutating, optional, override, postfix, precedence, prefix,
>   Protocol, required, right, set, Type, unowned, weak, and willSet.
>   Outside the context in which they appear in the grammar, they can be
>   used as identifiers.

Apparently, a top level enum Type is fine, but one embedded in a struct is not. The language reference section on Types > Metatype Types explains why:

> **Metatype Type**
>
> A metatype type refers to the type of any type, including class types, structure types, enumeration types, and protocol types.
>
> The metatype of a class, structure, or enumeration type is the name of
>   that type followed by .Type. The metatype of a protocol type—not the
>   concrete type that conforms to the protocol at runtime—is the name of
>   that protocol followed by .Protocol. For example, the metatype of the
>   class type SomeClass is SomeClass.Type and the metatype of the
>   protocol SomeProtocol is SomeProtocol.Protocol.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this (as mentioned before, Type is also used within the core of Swift. That's why the compiler is kind of confused). Type used as a name works if the enum is not nested:

```
enum Type {
        case One, Two, Three
}

struct S1 {

    let e1 : Type
    let i : Int
}

func f1(e : Type) {
   var x = S1(e1: Type.One, i: 1)
}

f1(Type.One)
```

if you use another name for the enum, you can still nest it:

```
 struct S2 {


    enum Kind {
        case One, Two, Three
    }

    let e1 : Kind
    let i : Int
}

func f2(e : S2.Kind) {
   var x = S2(e1: S2.Kind.One, i: 1)
}

f2(S2.Kind.One)
```